Which test should I use to evaluate if there is a change in proportion of two categorical variables over time if samples are not paired?
I am analyzing a dataset consisting of 100 clinical trials. For each of them, I have a categorical variable (conflict of interest reported: "yes"/"no") and an ordinal variable (year of publication). I would like to test if the ratio yes/no of the categorical variable statistically differ over time (hypothesis: recent studies report more often conflict of interests). Year of publication range from 2000 to 2020, and I can think to group them if necessary (e.g.: grouping studies published every 5 years). I came across Cochrane Q Test and McNemar's Test, but, as far as I have understood, both of them requires that the sample are paired, which, of course, is not the case (for each year I have a different set of studies).
Which is the best statistical test to use in this case?

It seems you may be searching for logistic regression. Avoid the temptation to collapse years as that wastes information.

Thank you very much. Could you explain me a bit more how to set up the analysis? I know that logistic regression can predict a categorical variable, but how can it be used to test differences in a time series? Thanks.
